# Connected and disconnected POCOs in EF

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

1. What does connected and disconnected "POCOs" mean in EF Code first?
2. Can you explain how to use these in different scenarios?

Answer (score 7):

When you use a Entity Framework DbContext to read objects from your database into your application these objects will be tracked by the context. This means that any changes you make to these objects will be persisted to the database when you call SaveChanges on the context.
This may be referred to as connected objects.

On the other hand you may want to pass these objects to another process. E.g. you may have a server that reads data from the database and then pass these objects on to a client. The client will receive pure poco objects that have no connection to the database. Any changes that the client may do to the objects will not automatically be detected by the server. This may be referred to as disconnected objects. I.e. they aren't tracked by the context.

The client may pass the objects, which may or may not have been changed by the client, back to the server. The server may then choose to attach the objects to the context and in this process turn a disconnected object into a connected object. In this case the server usually will have some functionality to detect deletions, additions and changes of the objects, but this is up to the developer of the server code to decide how this should work depending on the requirements of the application.

Comment: If I keep my DbContext alive during reading from DB, processing the resulted POCOs in the client and saving back the POCO's changes to DB using the same DbContext, I'm using connected. Am I correct?

Comment: It depends on if the POCOs you read and the POCOs you process are the same objects instances or not. E.g. when you serialize an object to send it to a different process where it is deserialized it is no longer the same object instance and no longer a connected object.

Comment: So, If I want to have a multi-tier application, I have to use disconnected POCOs, Is it right?